# If image is too large, automatically compress it

Tags: feature-request, images

I was thinking about uploading a picture

However, the image size is too large.

There are a lot of free-to-use `.jpeg` compression programs available on github.

What do you think about modifying the arts & crafts stack exchange website to automatically compress the image before uploading the file for hosting on [`imgur.com`](https://imgur.com)

[image: an animated gif of the image upload user interface. everything is grey except for pulsating red text complaining that the image size is too large]

Comment: The request is already in our backlog as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369424/automatically-resize-images-if-their-file-size-is-too-large, so I'm removing the [status-review] tag from this post to avoid duplicating requests — I suggest following that MSE post for any updates on this request (such changes would apply network-wide and not to this site specifically, in any case, so these requests generally have a better chance of getting implemented, and more views, when posted to MSE).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a brilliant idea. We regularly see post where users post links to images instead of the images themselves because they don't know how to include them correctly (including size constraints). Especially on mobile devices it can be very hard to compress an image without cropping it and then you never know exactly how much you need to compress it to fit without losing too much detail.

It's a real obstacle when users want to post pictures of the problem they ask about and all they say is "I made a photo with my phone but I cannot upload it".

Comment: This would be very helpful, not just here on A&C, but on several other Stacks that have images frequently posted. Just wondering about the number of Stacks that would benefit versus those that don't really need it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been raised on Meta a few times, the most recent of which seems to be this one: [Automatically resize images if their file size is too large](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369424/automatically-resize-images-if-their-file-size-is-too-large)

**Please upvote that request if you agree this should be changed!** Hopefully this will then get more attention.

The feature request has been [deferred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317672/422926) three years earlier (although not so much because of the nature of the request, but [because](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links/317672#comment1041985_317672) it was posted in the wrong place). It was requested before that in [2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273986/422926).

---

In the meantime, there are several easy ways of resizing images:

- You can simply use a search engine to find a bunch of **in-browser resizing tools**, like [here](https://www.ecosia.org/search?method=index&q=resize%20images%20online). Some of these make use of target file sizes.
- What I personally use in a pinch, in Windows 10, is the **Snipping Tool**.
  Using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, you can bring up a tool with which you can box-select part of, or copy the entire screen. This works great because you can just zoom in or out on an image in any image viewer, and select the relevant part of the picture, which will also allow you to leave any irrelevant information out).
  In the Snipping Tool window that pops up, you can simply save the image (and once you've opened this window, it will be temporarily stored in a cache in `%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_[xxxxx]\TempState` anyway).
- Naturally large files, such as PNG, can be saved as smaller file types (e.g. JPG) in **Paint**, which ships with all versions of Windows.
  I'm certain Macs have similar legacy tools.
- If you own software like **Photoshop**, this is probably not an issue to begin with, but it will allow you to change dimensions as well as compression algorithms (I use this, for example, to retain a balance between highest resolution and least lossy compression when uploading screenshots for the [Screenshot of the Week](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screenshot-of-the-week) feature on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)).